# How to sort date column in html table without any dependencies?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, date, html-table

I want to sort the Date column by latest and oldest date in my table.

I already tried codes below but it is not working. I don't have any idea how to sort the table since I am new to this field.

[image]

```
function convertDate(d) {
        var p = d.split("/");
        return +(p[2] + p[1] + p[0]);
    }

    function sortByDate() {
        var tbody = document.querySelector("#example tbody");
        // get trs as array for ease of use
        var rows = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"));
        rows.sort(function(a, b) {
            return convertDate(a.cells[7].innerHTML) - convertDate(b.cells[7].innerHTML);
        });

        rows.forEach(function(v) {
            tbody.appendChild(v); // note that .appendChild() *moves* elements
        });
    }

    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", sortByDate);

//retrieve data from firebase
 rootRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
        rootRef = childSnapshot.val();
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef.date));
        table.appendChild(tr);
    });


    function createCell(text) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        return td;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your data coming from originally?  Is it from a database or static?

Comment: @Jason Its from firebase realtime database

Comment: Can you do your sorting in the initial database query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you get your dates from, but assuming you can make an array out of them easily enough; I think a custom sort function would do the trick. Of course, you might get more elegant code using Date objects, but since there are only three sorting criteria, I don't see the point of over-engineering. This is the code I came up with :

```js
//test case date array
let dates = ["15-Dec-2015", "23-Feb-2029", "14-Apr-2009", "15-Apr-2009", '15-May-2009', '14-Apr-2004'];

//custom sorting
let sortedDates = dates.sort((a, b) => { //compare function
 const monthArray = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']; //month index
  //split a and b
 a = a.split('-'); 
 b = b.split('-');
  //compare years
 if(Number(a[2]) > Number(b[2]))
  return 1;
 if(Number(a[2]) < Number(b[2]))
  return -1;
  //compare months
 if(monthArray.indexOf(a[1]) > monthArray.indexOf(b[1]))
  return 1;
 if(monthArray.indexOf(a[1]) < monthArray.indexOf(b[1]))
  return -1;
  //compare days
 if(Number(a[0]) > Number(b[0]))
  return 1;
 if(Number(a[0]) < Number(b[0]))
  return -1;
});

console.log(sortedDates)
//returns ["14-Apr-2004", "14-Apr-2009", "15-Apr-2009", "15-May-2009", "15-Dec-2015", "23-Feb-2029"]
```

EDIT:

not sure if it'll work but I've tried to implement my code with your data :

```js
//test case date array
let dates;

function convertDate(d) {
        var p = d.split("/");
        return +(p[2] + p[1] + p[0]);
    }

    function sortByDate() {
        var tbody = document.querySelector("#example tbody");
        // get trs as array for ease of use
        var rows = [].slice.call(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"));
        rows.sort(function(a, b) {
            return convertDate(a.cells[7].innerHTML) - convertDate(b.cells[7].innerHTML);
        });

        rows.forEach(function(v) {
            tbody.appendChild(v); // note that .appendChild() *moves* elements
        });
    }

    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", sortByDate);

//retrieve data from firebase
 rootRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
        rootRef = childSnapshot.val();
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef.date));
        dates.push(rootRef.date);
        table.appendChild(tr);
    });


    function createCell(text) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        return td;
    }
    
    //custom sorting
let sortedDates = dates.sort((a, b) => { //compare function
 const monthArray = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']; //month index
  //split a and b
 a = a.split('-'); 
 b = b.split('-');
  //compare years
 if(Number(a[2]) > Number(b[2]))
  return 1;
 if(Number(a[2]) < Number(b[2]))
  return -1;
  //compare months
 if(monthArray.indexOf(a[1]) > monthArray.indexOf(b[1]))
  return 1;
 if(monthArray.indexOf(a[1]) < monthArray.indexOf(b[1]))
  return -1;
  //compare days
 if(Number(a[0]) > Number(b[0]))
  return 1;
 if(Number(a[0]) < Number(b[0]))
  return -1;
});

console.log(sortedDates)
```

Comment: How can I store the date from firebase into an array?

Comment: @Mary I really have no experience with Firebase. Does the data get sent out as a JSON object?

Comment: I updated my code on how I retrieve the data. Since I'm also new to this, I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Mary Ok I've edited my answer, tell me if the sortedDates log in your console.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. I will try to implement your codes.